# Python how to click multiple sub categories, get this error button">...</a> is not clickable at point (555, 55) Other element would receive the click

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i've got selenium to run and hit 2 sub categories via the X PATH already which are buttons and now i keep receiving the error above here again -

ole="button">... is not clickable at point (555, 55). Other element would receive the click: ...
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.163)

my code looks like this

"#More Faq page sub-categories
time.sleep(3)

WaysToWatch = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/section/div/div[2]/a')

WaysToWatch.click()

"#Set-pin - **THIS ONE DOESN'T WANT TO WORK**

time.sleep(5)

SetPin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/a')

SetPin.click()

I would appreciate a fix as I have quite a few of these I need to run through

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to click the button:

```
SetPin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/a')

script = 'arguments[0].click();'

driver.execute_script(script , SetPin)
```

This will allow you to click an element even if another is in front of it, but it doesn't simulate the actual user experience because of it.  Sometimes, you will want an error showing that another element will receive a click.

Also, it's a best practice to use waits to help prevent issues with interacting with elements before they're available.  You could do that with:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

locator = '//*[@id="main"]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/a'

SetPin = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, locator))

script = 'arguments[0].click();'

driver.execute_script(script , SetPin)
```

Comment: Still doesn't work when I try that, anyone else got any suggestions but in Python

Comment: You get the same error when using the javascript solution in my answer?  I'm not sure how that would be, but if there is more information that you can provide like an updated error message and the html then I can try to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below answer using javascript click or you can also try with ActcionChains

```
          element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/a')))
          driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

or

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/a')))     

ActcionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

**Note:**  add below imorts to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.HOME)

## Use send_keys(Keys.HOME) to scroll up to the top of page